# linux kernel module hooking certain system calls cannot see string parameters in user space

Tags: c, linux, kernel, hook, system-calls

I am doing an exercise for a class to hook some system calls on a running kernel using a linux kernel module and using my new_sys_call() in place of the old one. I am developing on CentOS 7 and using a stock kernel-3.10.0-862.3.2. I was able to successfully hook execve and I can access parameter values but I cannot seem to access the rename syscall parameter values. I realize this is probably not a practical real world approach but I am trying to learn more about kernel development and how system calls work.

Here's an example of the hooking method definitions:

```
/*
   Original Syscall Prototype
*/
asmlinkage long (*orig_sys_chdir_fn)(const char __user *filename);

/*
new syscall
*/
asmlinkage long new_sys_chdir(const char __user *filename) {

   // do stuff
   return orig_sys_chdir_fn(filename);
}
```

We obtain the stub chdir address with this code:

```
orig_stub_chdir_addr = ((unsigned long *)(sys_call_table_addr))[__NR_chdir];



  Thread 357 hit Breakpoint 3, new_sys_rename (oldname=0xffffff9c <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffff9c>,
    newname=0xffffff9c <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffff9c>) at /home/ulys/syshooks/kmod/sysrename.c:19
19      asmlinkage long new_sys_rename(const char __user *oldname,  const char __user *newname) {
(gdb) info registers
rax            0xffffffff8122dbd0       -2128421936
rbx            0x0      0
rcx            0x7ffd0faf9480   140724866618496
rdx            0xffffff9c       4294967196
rsi            0xffffff9c       4294967196
rdi            0xffffff9c       4294967196
rbp            0xffff88004183bf48       0xffff88004183bf48
rsp            0xffff88004183bf40       0xffff88004183bf40
r8             0x0      0
r9             0x1      1
r10            0x7ffd0faf7320   140724866609952
r11            0x202    514
r12            0x0      0
r13            0x0      0
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x0      0
rip            0xffffffffc0540b20       0xffffffffc0540b20 <new_sys_rename>
eflags         0x10246  [ PF ZF IF RF ]
cs             0x10     16
ss             0x18     24
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0xb      11
(gdb) info stack
#0  new_sys_rename (oldname=0xffffff9c <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffff9c>,
    newname=0xffffff9c <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffff9c>) at /home/ulys/syshooks/kmod/sysrename.c:19
#1  0xffffffff8122dbee in gather_surplus_pages (delta=-2123237509, h=0x0 <irq_stack_union>) at mm/hugetlb.c:1764
#2  hugetlb_acct_memory (h=0x0 <irq_stack_union>, delta=-2123237521) at mm/hugetlb.c:3149
#3  0xffffffff8171f82f in inet_netconf_fill_devconf (skb=0xffffffff8171f77b <inet_netconf_fill_devconf+123>,
    ifindex=<optimized out>, devconf=<optimized out>, portid=<optimized out>, seq=<optimized out>, flags=<optimized out>,
    type=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x10>, event=80) at net/ipv4/devinet.c:1786
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) x/s 0x7ffd0faf9480
0x7ffd0faf9480: "/tmp/test2"
```

You can see the bogus addresses at 0xffffff9c which cannot be read by copy_from_user or used by anything in the new_sys_rename function. You can see that the newname is in the register rcx but I can't locate oldname. I have noticed this on several different filename based syscalls such as chmod and chdir as well.

On chdir, I receive similar results except I can't find filename in any register.

```
Thread 304 hit Breakpoint 1, new_sys_chdir (
    filename=0xffffff9c <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffff9c>)
    at /home/ulys/syshooks/kmod/syschdir.c:17
17      asmlinkage long new_sys_chdir(const char __user *filename) {
(gdb) info registers
rax            0x0      0
rbx            0x0      0
rcx            0xffff880055d47f18       -131939955343592
rdx            0x3      3
rsi            0x3      3
rdi            0xffffff9c       4294967196
rbp            0xffff880055d47f48       0xffff880055d47f48
rsp            0xffff880055d47f10       0xffff880055d47f10
r8             0xc919d0 13179344
r9             0xcba2d0 13345488
r10            0x7f7147cfd030   140124512833584
r11            0x246    582
r12            0x3      3
r13            0xc8f320 13169440
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x0      0
rip            0xffffffffc0561000       0xffffffffc0561000 <new_sys_chdir>
eflags         0x10246  [ PF ZF IF RF ]
cs             0x10     16
ss             0x18     24
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0xb      11
(gdb) x/s 0xffff880055d47f18
0xffff880055d47f18:     "o\367q\201\377\377\377\377{\367q\201\377\377\377\377\225\"", <incomplete sequence \356>
(gdb) x/s 0xc919d0
0xc919d0:       " "
(gdb) x/s 0xc919d0
0xc919d0:       " "
(gdb) x/s 0x7f7147cfd030
0x7f7147cfd030: "f\017s\372\005f\017t\321f\017\370\320fD\017\327\312\323\352A\323\351D)\312\017\205\v\004"
(gdb) info stack
#0  new_sys_chdir (filename=0xffffff9c <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffff9c>)
    at /home/ulys/syshooks/kmod/syschdir.c:17
#1  0xffffffff81218b3e in move_page_tables (vma=<optimized out>, old_addr=3, new_vma=<optimized out>,
    new_addr=18446744071586314095, len=<optimized out>, need_rmap_locks=<optimized out>) at mm/mremap.c:187
#2  0xffffffff8171f82f in inet_netconf_fill_devconf (skb=0xffffffff8171f77b <inet_netconf_fill_devconf+123>,
    ifindex=<optimized out>, devconf=<optimized out>, portid=<optimized out>, seq=<optimized out>, flags=<optimized out>,
    type=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x10>, event=80) at net/ipv4/devinet.c:1786
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

It appears to work just fine on execve. Here you can see similar output but I have no problems accessing any of execve's filename or argv strings.

```
Thread 335 hit Breakpoint 2, new_sys_execve (filename=0x55c85e0d7af0 "/usr/libexec/postfix/pickup", argv=0x55c85e0d3d00,
    envp=0x55c85e0d3d00) at /home/ulys/syshooks/kmod/sysexecve.c:21
21              const char __user * const __user * envp) {
(gdb) info registers
rax            0xffffffff8171fd80       -2123235968
rbx            0x0      0
rcx            0xffffffff       4294967295
rdx            0x55c85e0d3d00   94319059746048
rsi            0x55c85e0d3d00   94319059746048
rdi            0x55c85e0d7af0   94319059761904
rbp            0x0      0x0 <irq_stack_union>
rsp            0xffff88005323ff50       0xffff88005323ff50
r8             0x30     48
r9             0x0      0
r10            0xffffffff       4294967295
r11            0x206    518
r12            0x0      0
r13            0x0      0
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x0      0
rip            0xffffffffc053f880       0xffffffffc053f880 <new_sys_execve>
eflags         0x10282  [ SF IF RF ]
cs             0x10     16
ss             0x18     24
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0xb      11
(gdb) info stack
#0  new_sys_execve (filename=0x55c85e0d7af0 "/usr/libexec/postfix/pickup", argv=0x55c85e0d3d00, envp=0x55c85e0d3d00)
    at /home/ulys/syshooks/kmod/sysexecve.c:21
#1  0xffffffff8171fdc8 in rtm_to_ifaddr (pprefered_lft=<synthetic pointer>, pvalid_lft=<synthetic pointer>,
    nlh=0x0 <irq_stack_union>, net=0x0 <irq_stack_union>) at net/ipv4/devinet.c:801
#2  inet_rtm_newaddr (skb=0x0 <irq_stack_union>, nlh=0x0 <irq_stack_union>) at net/ipv4/devinet.c:854
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x8
```

So why are some of these variables protected from kernel space? Where can they be found and is there another kernel function that can be called to get the values?

Comment: I can only suggest you look at the original implementation and see how it behaves. Yours would be the same.

Comment: Post your code.  All your invalid addresses appear to be 32-bit values.